# Why the map function not executing after promise?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

Here is my code:

```
let promise = new Promise(( resolve ) => {
        let dataArray = d3.csvParse(csvData);
        return resolve(dataArray);
    });

    promise.then(( dataArray: Array<Object> ) => {
        return _(dataArray).transform(( result, item, name ) => {
            result[ item.district ]         = result[ item.district ] || {};
            result[ item.district ][ name ] = item;
            return result;
        }).value();

    }).then(data => data.map(d => console.log(d))); // not loading
```

I am using d3 to parse a csv file. After the parsing is done I am resolving the promise and trying to execute a chain of lodash operations on the returned array. I tried chaining the methods of transform and map and also tried forcing chain by using `_.chain(...)`.

The console does not return any errors, and I can log the data array in the `then` part.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map is meant to be used with arrays. Here, your `result` array contains no items but as much propeties as existing districts.

```
result[ item.district ]         = result[ item.district ] || {};
```

Therefore, you could use Object.keys(data).map() instead of map:

```
.then(data => {
    Object.keys(data).map(function(elem) { console.log(data[elem]); });
})
```

https://runkit.com/587b513664a8d4001433714a/587b63902c363d0014cc3964

Comment: thank you for your answer. I see what you mean. Is there a way to do this in lodash? maybe using mapKeys/mapValues?

Comment: I must admit I don't use lodash and it depends on what you want to achieve when you map. From what I understand, mapKeys will be used to change the object properties names so I don't think it's what you want. mapValues maybe ...

Answer (score 0):

If you add reject and catch to your promise, you could possibly see code errors. It's about your "The console does not return any errors".
All this stuff you can find in MDN Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining 
Also, I think you should remove return in "return resolve(dataArray);", because Promise waits for resolve, you don't need to return it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did add reject and catch later and there is still no errors. I'll definitely check your link